# Использование ключевого слова const в заголовках методов класса

Tags: c++

Прошу детально объяснить зачем в этом примере кода используют ключевое слово const? Ведь без него все работает точно также.

```
#include<string>
using std::string;

class CommissionEmployee
{
public:
CommissionEmployee(const string &, const string &, const string &, double =0.0, double = 0.0);
void setFirstName(const string &);
getFirstName() const;
}
```

Comment: Какой из двух случаев вас интересует? `foo(const T &)` или `T foo() const`?

Comment: Приводите более-менее корректный код. Куда пропал возвращемый тип у `getFirstName()`?

Comment: const не влияет на саму работу. Это спецификатор доступа. Можно понимать как "это нельзя менять". В отношении функции означает: "эта функция ничего не меняет", что при компиляции позволяет оптимизировать код.

Comment: Интересует оба случая

Comment: @Кирилл Ненахов второй случай я уже описал, а первый вообще проще простого: переменная не изменяется. Передаётся по ссылке, но изменять её нельзя. С одной стороны это позволяет избежать копирования объекта, а с другой защищает его от изменения.